# How can I check if an iptables rule already exists?

Tags: iptables

I need to add a rule to iptables to block connections to a tcp port from the Internet.

Since my script may be called multiple times and there is not a script to delete the rule, I want to check if an iptables rule already exists before inserting it - otherwise there will be a lot of dup rules in the INPUT chain.

How can I check if an iptables rule already exists?

Comment: Alternatively, use this wrapper, which provides idempotent iptables interaction : https://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/idemptables/

Comment: If you use a shell script to build your firewall, look below at my bash function to make it dead simple.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is a new `-C --check` option in recent iptables versions.

```
# iptables -C INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 --jump ACCEPT
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
# echo $?
1

# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 --jump ACCEPT

# iptables -C INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 --jump ACCEPT
# echo $?
0
```

For older iptables versions, I would use Garrett suggestion :

```
# iptables-save | grep -- "-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT"
```

Comment: In firewalld you can use the `--query-rule` option

Answer (score 13):

The new `-C` option is not satisfactory, because it is open to a time-of-check-to-time-of-use (TOCTTOU) race condition. If two processes try to add the same rule at around the same time, `-C` will not protect them from adding it twice.

So, it is really no better than the `grep` solution. An accurate text processing job over the output of `iptables-save` can work as reliably as `-C`, since that output is a reliable snapshot of the state of the tables.

What is needed is an `--ensure` option which atomically checks and adds a rule only if it doesn't already exist.  Moreover, it would be nice if the rule is moved to the correct position where a new rule would be inserted if it did not exist already (`--ensure-move`). For instance if `iptables -I 1` is used to create a rule at the head of a chain, but that rule exists already in the seventh position, then the existing rule should move to the
first position.

Without these features, I think a feasible workaround is to write a shell script loop based on this pseudo code:

```
while true ; do
  # delete all copies of the rule first

  while copies_of_rule_exist ; do
    iptables -D $RULE
  done

  # now try to add the rule

  iptables -A $RULE # or -I 

  # At this point there may be duplicates due to races.
  # Bail out of loop if there is exactly one, otherwise
  # start again.
  if exactly_one_copy_of_rule_exists ; then
    break;
  fi
done
```

This code could spin around; it does not guarantee that two or more racers will be out within a fixed number of iterations. Some randomized exponential backoff sleeps could be added to help with that.

Comment: May I add that this command is rather not satisfactory for the simple reason that you have to pinpoint the exact way your rule was added. I made the test with my setup, and it couldn't find a rule because I didn't specify the exact keywords and values...

Comment: If you temporarily remove a rule then you might break something...

Answer (score 9):

This may seem a bit backwards, but it works for me.

Try deleting the rule first.

```
iptables -D INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP;
```

You should get a message similiar to:

```
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?)
```

Then simply add your rule as normal:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP;
```

Comment: Opening an unwanted hole in your firewall, just to simulate an idempotent command, is probably not a great idea. Sure, the hole is intended to be temporary, but it still improves an attacker's chances. And if something interrupts the addition of the replacement rule, then the hole could persist indefinitely.

Comment: Good point @sampablokuper: this strategy is probably only suitable for ACCEPT rules and not DROP ones, for security reasons

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing!

Answer (score 4):

Just list and search for it?

```
iptables --list | grep $ip
```

... or however you have the rule specified. If you use `grep -q` it won't output anything, and you can just check the return value with `$?`

Comment: I would suggest `iptables-save|grep $ip` instead as it is a more easily parseable format, especially in a script. You can check the exact syntax of the command too if you want.

Comment: Neither of these actually answers the question, because `iptables-save|grep $ip` could very well match *multiple* rules.  Possibly `iptables-save` could be used to check for the *complete* rule specification, but that's still a bit of a hack: the format returned by `iptables-save` may not match exactly the rule in the script. `iptables-save` may generate the options in a different order, add things (like `-m tcp`), and so forth.

Comment: Bear in mind that `iptables --list` will try to resolve well-known ports. So make sure of that before you grep for a port.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid duplicate rules from your script, add below line.

```
iptables -C -INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 --jump ACCEPT || iptables -A -INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 --jump ACCEPT
```

First time when above command is run, we would observe below message

```
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
```

This is just for information. But second half of the command would ensure to add the rule.

Answer (score 0):

How about first adding and then removing duplicates as described in https://serverfault.com/questions/628590/duplicate-iptable-rules. Easiest (for adjacent lines) [seems to be](https://serverfault.com/a/890065/317052)

```
iptables-save | uniq | iptables-restore
```

Comment: it is going to delete commit and other metadata lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say for adding in a systemd exception 'ExecPreStart' for iptables for KVM and DOCKER to live happily with Linux bridging networks, this return -1 makes the docker systemd daemon FAIL. UGH....

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233727

Trying to delete an old table will make it fail and docker service wont start. Using the check method will fail. In the end YOU have to write

1. a bash script that will check okayishly if iptables rule is present
2. you have to hadd the execprestart to run that script instead of just trying to add the rule or check using only iptables command (god i wish it was implemmented better)
3. Now you have to ansbile the god damn thing! Its the same with fockin cron jobs. You have to create so many files!

OK nvm the Check command works as intended.

Ansible loops over all the bridges I have and adds them which is neat. Crisis averted.

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/usr/sbin/iptables -C FORWARD -p all -i vlanbr1 -o vlanbr1 -j ACCEPT || /usr/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i vlanbr1 -o vlanbr1 -j ACCEPT'
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/usr/sbin/iptables -C FORWARD -p all -i vlanbr2 -o vlanbr2 -j ACCEPT || /usr/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i vlanbr2 -o vlanbr2 -j ACCEPT'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, so I created a small function for bash shell script to handle adding rules only if they do not exists.

***Note: This is a preventative measure to avoid duplicates rather than a reactive cleanup solution.***

The benefit is that my script still looks like standard iptables commands and you can easily run the fw commands manually by just stripping off the prefixed underscore after copy/paste.

> Obviously this code could be improved greatly with error checking
> and/or better general robustness, but it's succinct and works well
> enough as-is. YMMV

> You can remove the echo statements to make the script silent.  I put them in for code clarity sake here.

```
#!/bin/sh

_iptables()
{
  #split the passed iptables command into the main component parts
  ARG="$@"      #grab the entire rule definition passed to function
  ACTION=$1     #our action is the first parameter [IAD]
  RULE=${@:2}   #grab all remaining members of the argarray starting at position 2. 
  
  #use the "check" functionality of recent iptables to see if rule is a dupe
  # iptables returns 1 if rule does not exist, 0 if it already exists
  iptables -C $RULE 2>/dev/null
  if [ $? -eq 1 ];then
    #add rule since it doesn't already exist
    iptables $ARG
    echo "Added iptables rule: $RULE"
  else
    echo "FW rule not added (already exists?)"
  fi
}

####################################################
#### Usage examples ################################
####################################################
# Syntax:
# _iptables -[ACD] chain rule-specification [options]
####################################################
_iptables -I FORWARD -i br1 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
_iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br1 -j ACCEPT

_iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o tun21 -j MASQUERADE

_iptables -I banned_ips -s 12.34.56.78 -j DROP
_iptables -I banned_ips -s 23.45.67.89 -j DROP
```